# Unable to login in docker via CLI using Ubuntu machine

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am able to Login via Dockerhub GUI, but if I'm doing the same via CLI, then I get an error.

[image: Am using the username as numbers and lowercase]

Note: I am only using username, not the email id while login to docker. I have tried everything, for example:

`proxy server config.`,
`docker restart`,
`logout`, `login` etc...

Docker version I am using is `17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6`

I need to pull an image from Dockerhub, so I am trying to login in Docker.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: if you are using in docker windows then try login the docker desktop app.

Comment: We are trying to use in Terminal using ubuntu machine.

Comment: Can you please attach the docker info commands output. That will give more information.

Comment: Did u add the docker user group and your ubuntu user to that group?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
I hope you are not running in a corporate network and ubuntu inside a VM.